How is the Extraordinary Means of Salvation in Catholicism not Pelagianism? (Cathechism 847)
The Catholic Catechism #847 gives exception to the (ordinary) rule of need for baptism for salvation. This extraordinary means is found outside the visible church, in the invisible church in righteousness through conscience, while being ignorant of the direct revelation of God (cf Rom 2:6-16). Thus, the unevangelised and ill-evangelised may typically fall under it.

Catechism #847: Those who, through no fault of their own, do not know the Gospel of Christ or his Church, but who nevertheless seek God with a sincere heart, and, moved by grace, try in their actions to do his will as they know it through the dictates of their conscience - those too may achieve eternal salvation.

This development from Augustine has been reportedly credited to Aquinas 13th century who talked about "baptism of desire" where someone who desired baptism but died before receiving it could be saved by their desire and repentance; Council of Trent (1545–1563) and Second Vatican Council (1962–1965).
Pelagianism is defined by the denial of Augustinian Original sin, that man has free will to achieve perfection, original sin did not taint human nature. The Catholicism also rejects the tainted nature of man due to original sin. The essential characteristic for salvation in Pelagianism is defined by righteousness, rather than religion or baptism/sacrament. It is best described as Synergism, which rejects Monergism with respect to salvation.
The difference between the Catholic and Pelagian view maybe seen in the language and perspective, where Catholics may use the term grace or mercy to be the cause of salvation, whereas Pelagius would call it justice. The question is how do Catholic scholars differentiate it with Pelagianism? Is the difference merely of the initiation of the salvation process? Is it right to call Catholic view Pelagianism, except for the initiation?
Semi-Pelagianism was condemned as heresy at the Second Council of Orange in 529 CE, which emphasized that the initiative for salvation lies with God alone, and that human beings cannot take the first step toward God without divine grace.

I don't understand the question. Catholicism itself rejects Pelagianism entirely. The cited "Extraordinary means" doesn't fundamentally change the relationship between grace, will and salvation in Catholic doctrine; that is, if one is Pelegian, the other would be as well.

"Semi-Pelagian" seems to be a Protestant label used against Catholics / Arminians.   Useful intro: sections on Arminianism and Jansenism from Wikipedia article on Semi-Pelagianism. Maybe it is more useful to ask to compare the "semi-pelagian" stance of Catholicism today (shown through the references you cited) with the "semi-pelagianism" that was condemned as heresy at the Second Council of Orange (529 CE).  What's tricky when using a term that has "semi" in it, is that it muddles the contrast in the gray middle.

@GratefulDisciple if the dispute about semi is only about initiative of the salvation process so to give god greater credit, then this whole issue maybe missing the key point of division between Pelagian and Augustine, that it's about freewill and mainly natural immunity to sin which allows salvation outside of baptism. In this case Catholic view should be included in Pelagianism and Molinism.

Pelagianism pertains to the need for grace, and grace is needed in cases of extraordinary means; therefore the notion of extraordinary means is not Pelagian.

@zippy2006 that distinction is purely of perspective like semi-pelagianism, to argue that Pelagius' salvation was stealing or winning against God illegitimately to obtain the tree of life, by saying it's without grace. It's just a formal assumption. There is fundamentally no difference, and what is evident is the mention of grace is completely unnecessary and unrelated here, as it's posed in favour of fatalism/determinism of Augustine/Calvinism, and against freewill.
